# How to launch Google Maps Driving Mode after Assistant Driving Mode Shutdown in November 2022?

Tags: driving-mode

I have an older car with no Android Auto built in. I used the Android Auto feature on my phone screen all the time before it was disabled in Android 12.

This forced me to switch to the Assistant Driving Mode screen, which was OK and would auto-launch when I got in my car.

This was now also [shut down](https://www.theverge.com/2022/10/9/23395917/google-getting-standalone-driving-mode-dashboard-maps-android-auto), and apparently I am supposed to use the Google Maps Driving Mode instead. But I don't really understand how I can launch it. Assistant Driving Mode would auto-launch, and it would also have a persistent notification that could be used to open it while connected to the car via bluetooth. This is no longer the case.
All of the articles I'm seeing are saying that you need to start navigating in Google Maps to start the driving mode there, but that can't be the only way? I use Driving Mode to make calls and play podcasts, and mostly drive around my town where I have no need for navigation. So is there another way to launch driving mode without starting navigation in Google Maps?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible on a car or not, but on a phone/tablet, Google Maps has a Driving Mode shortcut widget that can be placed on the homescreen.

Comment: Thank you, that does somewhat work. It will launch a near-driving mode screen, but only allows starting navigation. Music and call controls are not available until I start navigation. It seems this is the current state of things, and in my opinion quite an asinine design decision by Google. But anyway, @AndrewT. I think your comment is as close to the answer I'm looking for as it can be, so if you would post it as an answer, I'll consider this the correct one.

Comment: Feel free to post a self-answer because you know the details and limitations better :)